# Cloud Spanner Key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I read [docs](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-design) and can't figure out how to generate unique key using cloud-spanner. In SQL we have AUTOINCREMENT but it's anti-pattern in cloud-spanner. In docs UserId apear like: 001930, 001519, 011289, 010483, 000241 but didn't say how they generate these ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to generate your unique key values client side. There are no AUTOINCREMENT, SEQUENCE or other key generation options available server side in Cloud Spanner. You could do this client side with for example (the hash of) UUID's.

Comment: So using UUIDv5 will generate a unique id like "a0e6a3d6-aab2-49fc-a214-f26a1e3985e4" we can store it as a string(pretty large) and it will serve as a unique ID of that row. Can cloud-spanner use a string like the one above as a first and a timestamp secound primary key to mitigate the hotspot or I need to hash the UUID to INT(because the UUIDv5 can have alphanumeric character at start.

Comment: You could also store the UUID in a BYTES(16) column instead of as a string in order to save space. But I choose to rely on the hash of a randomly generated UUID as primary key. See this short article for an example: http://cloudspanner.blogspot.de/2017/09/google-cloud-spanner-with-jpa-and.html

Comment: So using a UUID(v4 for really random) "ddb52691-20a6-4fea-b1b6-bc6840fa1485" we can use it as a primary key without any problem(even with alphanumeric characters) but you suggest to hash the UUID just for the reason of saving space ?("ddb52691-20a6-4fea-b1b6-bc6840fa1484" -> "79f836782bcbb8ef159b1eef8ad7da7d" ? Another question, why you would a primary key compose from 2 keys what's the reason behind that ?

Comment: The reason that I choose to use the hash of a UUID as my primary key is that I use Cloud Spanner for an application that was previously running on PostgreSQL, and that was already using integer values as primary keys on all tables. But yes, also to potentially save some space. In my example application I preserve the UUID value as well, meaning that I don't really save any space, but the UUID is NOT part of the primary key. Note that using the hash of a UUID is also what Google suggest: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-and-data-model#choosing_a_primary_key

Comment: One more question, what kind of hashing algorithm you recomand for hashing UUID(hash string to string(MD5 or something else?) or hash string(UUID) to int(some example and best practive please)? And why you need to hash something that's already random generated if spanner can process STRING as PRIMARY KEY ?

Comment: I do an XOR of the 32 most significant bits and the 32 least significant bits. You haven't said anything about what programming language you are using. Using Java, the hash looks simply like this: id = uuid.getMostSignificantBits() ^ uuid.getLeastSignificantBits(); (uuid being an instance of the class UUID)

Comment: I use Javascript, "And why you need to hash something that's already random generated if spanner can process STRING as PRIMARY KEY ?". Is any performance hit when spanner check primary key STRING not INT ?

Comment: I don't think the performance hit is really significant, but the extra storage is. Storing an INT64 takes up 8 bytes, storing a String with length 36 takes up at least 36 bytes. As you plan to use it for your Primary Key, it will also be stored in a unique index, meaning that you can multiply the difference by 2. 28*2=56 bytes extra for each row makes a real difference. And as I mentioned in one of my previous comments: I chose to use an INT64 hash value of a UUID because I wanted to continue using an application already using a PK based on an integer value.

Comment: I understand why you chose this method but when you create new UUID and hash it down to INT64(can you please recomand any hashing method to hash UUID into INT64) you lose the guarantee uniqueness(because UUID require 128 bites to guarantee uniqueness and we hash it to 64). The solution is to check in DB if the generated UUID hash exist in DB or not ? Thank you for previous replies

Comment: You're right, there is no guarantee that the 64-bit hash of a UUID is unique, but assuming that the random UUID generator is good and your hash function is good, the chance of getting overlapping id's is still extremely small. I'm afraid I can't help you with a good Javascript function for hashing a UUID, other than my previous general description of my hash function: XOR the 8 most significant bytes with the 8 least significant bytes of the UUID.

Answer (score 0):

To update the answer here, Cloud Spanner now supports auto incrementing.  You can make use of `GENERATE_UUID()` to accomplish auto incrementing and avoid hotspots.

You can read more in Google's blog post: [Simplifying best practices at scale with auto-generated keys in Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/announcing-support-for-auto-generated-keys-in-spanner)